# How to change resource file in .NET core in class library

Tags: c#, .net-core

**How to change resource file in .NET core in-class library**

I created multiple created resource files. When I am trying to access it's not able to access.

```
ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Language.Resources.String",
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var currentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
     CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");

var NewcurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
var string = resourceManager.GetString("hello");
```

but language not changed its still  only

I am getting below error

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find the resource "Language.Resources.String.resources" among the resources "" embedded in the assembly "Language", nor among the resources in any satellite assemblies for the specified culture. Perhaps the resources were embedded with an incorrect name.'

Comment: What's the output of [Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: Issues resolved Microsoft tutorial its help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager?view=net-6.0